# API parameter naming scheme

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, design-patterns

Passing the parameter "category" to an API can mean either filtering or updating the parameter in DB. What is the best practice/design for naming API parameters?

For example, I might send a request to update an item and updating its category, by filtering with category. Then I have the category parameter twice. How should I best name them?

Right now I have "filter_category" and "set_category" in which I then remove the prefix through a function that checks with a predefined prefix list.

Comment: Normaly you use query parameters for filtering (GET) and post bodies (POST) for payloads. For example `POST { category_id: 1 } ../my-api/items?category_id=2` This wil set the category_id to 1 where category_id = 2 for example (readable way).

Comment: Ok thanks, then I have to just separate the GET parameters with the other method's parameters, right?